# What extension should be used for creating a configuration file for a program?

Tags: configuration-files, file-extension

There are various extensions being used for configuration or initialization files across many operating systems and programming languages.

Some examples include: .cnf, .ini, .cfg

What would be a good choice for cross-platform program or script to use for configuration file extension?

Answer (score 0):

Depends on:

- the technology you are (e.g. ASP.Net uses web.config files that can be modified without recompiling)
- on what level you want to use the configuration file

  - XML might be appropriate (and is widely used)
  - just plain text will do as well (but might be harder to interpret)

..just use whatever sounds the coolest to you.

Comment: At the moment I am using plain text. You have a good point about XML, XML or JSON format could be used, in that case they have their own extensions.